# Hyperlink from a class to another diagram in IBM Rational Software Architect 9.0?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, uml, ibm-rational, rational-rsa

In RSA 9.0, is there a way to put a diagram hyperlink on a class such that when I double click that class, the defining diagram for that class opens? A competing tool called MagicDraw supports this functionality. Is there a similar feature in RSA? I've looked long and hard in the RSA help and in online forums and come up empty handed.

Note: I do NOT want to put a diagram beneath a class, such that the class owns it, because one diagram can define several classes.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option "Navigate to Diagram" that shows up in the context menu of several elements that is supposed to do precisely this. This can even be done from different views (Project explorer, search view etc)

Comment: Does that show all the diagrams containing the class? Can I differentiate the one fully defining diagram for the class?